# Conditional environment variables tree-shaking

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, tree-shaking

Currently I am trying to remove unused code based on the environment variable.
In the code below when I run `ng build --prod` and set `evironment.showDevTools = false` in `environment.prod.ts` then I expect the `console.log` not to be included in the final build file, but unfortunately it is. What am I doing wrong?

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

if (environment.showDevTools) {
  console.log('showing dev-tools');
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-component',
  templateUrl: './app.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {

}
```

Part of main.js

```
,ut=n("AytR");ut.a.showDevTools&&console.log("showing dev-tools");var st=function(){
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to add a field called `"sideEffects": false` to the `package.json`. So it currently looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "myApp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "sideEffects": false,
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "test": "ng test",
    ...
  },
}
```

References: https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/, https://github.com/stereobooster/package.json#sideeffects